# test a development ipa file on a not jailbroken ipad

Tags: ios, jailbreak, provisioning, ipa

I'm developing an app for a customer and to show it on his device I sent him the ipa file of the app and his device was jailbroken and he successfully installed the file on his device. but now he wants to install the app on a not jailbroken device and I have the device UDID and I added that device to a new provisioning profile and rebuild the app with that profile . and recreated a new ipad file . but this also didn't help and he couldn't install the file . 
is there any way to test the ipa file on a not jailbroken device? 
I will appreciate if someone can help me with this 
thanks

Comment: This is a very valid and popular question. Why was this down voted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add UDID in device section on iTunes connect account then create an adHoc provisioning profile selecting the device and then use this provisioning to archive application in XCode then send him the ipa and the provisioning profile.
If you want there is a fantastic website http://testflightapp.com that allow you to send ipa OTA and there is a lot of explanation on how to create and send ipa.

Comment: thanks I signed up on testflight and seems it's a very great service for testing apps . thanks again for your recommendation

Comment: I think because is generic, otherwise I don't know.